# echange rate from LOC/EUR to EUR

Tags: exchange-rates

I have import values in LOCEUR (LOC is local currency). 
How can I obtain these values only in EUR? [My data are from Eurostat](https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?query=BOOKMARK_DS-063319_QID_-622CB371_UID_-3F171EB0&layout=TIME,C,X,0;GEO,L,Y,0;INDIC_ET,L,Z,0;SITC06,L,Z,1;PARTNER,L,Z,2;INDICATORS,C,Z,3;&zSelection=DS-063319PARTNER,EXT_EU28;DS-063319INDIC_ET,MIO_EXP_VAL;DS-063319SITC06,TOTAL;DS-063319INDICATORS,OBS_FLAG;&rankName1=PARTNER_1_2_-1_2&rankName2=SITC06_1_2_-1_2&rankName3=INDIC-ET_1_2_-1_2&rankName4=INDICATORS_1_2_-1_2&rankName5=TIME_1_0_0_0&rankName6=GEO_1_2_0_1&sortC=ASC_-1_FIRST&rStp=&cStp=&rDCh=&cDCh=&rDM=true&cDM=true&footnes=false&empty=false&wai=false&time_mode=ROLLING&time_most_recent=false&lang=EN&cfo=%23%23%23%2C%23%23%23.%23%23%23), where external trade indicator is "Exports in million of ECU/EURO"

Comment: Would be helpful to know where you got your data. What's the data frequency? Would using average exchange rate be ok?

Comment: @Art I add this information to my question.

Comment: @Art How average exchange rate should look like?

Comment: I followed your link but it seems to show export share or something. So you have exports in Euros already? I'm a bit confused what you need.

Comment: @Art in my link you should choose options where external trade indicator is "Exports in million of ECU/EURO in which I'm interested. I try to set good link

Comment: If you mean you want to convert ECU to EURO, they are essentially the same currency; one was a basket of European currencies used before 1 Jan 1999, the other is used after. The exchange rate is exactly 1 ECU = 1 EURO. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Currency_Unit#Euro_replaces_ECU So you should be able to use that as EUROs.

Comment: @Art Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to convert ECU to EURO, they are essentially the same currency; one was a basket of European currencies used before 1 Jan 1999, the other is used after. The exchange rate is exactly 1 ECU = 1 EURO ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Currency_Unit#Euro_replaces_ECU)) So you should be able to use that as EUROs.

*Note:* This came from my comment above, which I take that it helped the OP. Just to boost up answered questions ratio for this site.